How to get parent div to shrink to the size of its child video element - Inconsistent across browsers
I have a video element which is nested in a div. This div is nested within another div.
<div className={styles.centerSection}>
    <div className={styles.videoContainer}>
      <video
        className={styles.videoPlayer}
        loop
        muted
        autoPlay
        ref={videoRef}
      >
        <source src={pickedVideo} />
      </video>
    </div>
</div>

The problem I'm having is that I want the .videoContainer (green) to shrink to the size of the .videoPlayer (blue) and not expand to the size of the .centerSection (red). I've looked at other StackOverflow questions and searched elsewhere but haven't been successful.
What I'm currently getting is shown in the below image. .centerSection has a red border. .videoContainer has a green border. .videoPlayer has a blue border.

The css that achieved this result is as follows.
.centerSection {
  border: 6px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.videoContainer {
  border: 6px solid green;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.videoPlayer {
  border: 6px solid blue;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

How do I get the .videoContainer (green) to tightly wrap the .videoPlayer (blue)?
Update:
It turns out that the above CSS performs as I would expect on Chrome browser but not in Firefox, which I've been using all along. How do I get it to also work on Firefox/across browsers?

Try  display: inline-flex; on the container?

.videoContainer has a max-width property of 100%. Have you tried setting it to fit-children instead?

Thanks for the replys guys, but neither inline-flex or fit-content have worked unfortunately

When I run your code, the blue and green borders do wrap around the video.

That's strange, can you think of any reason why that might be the case. Could the parent element of .centerSection influence it?

So I've just figured out that it works in chrome browser, but not firefox, which I've been using all along. Not exactly sure why yet. Will look into how to enforce it on firefox, if anyone has any suggestions, it'd be appreciated :)
